# Using Bootstrap 5 with Vue 3

Tags: vuejs3, bootstrap-5

I want to use Bootstrap 5 with Vue 3. As Bootstrap 5 uses vanilla JS (no JQuery), can I use Bootstrap 5 directly in a Vue 3 project (without using Bootstrap-Vue)? Can someone guide me how to use Bootstrap 5 with Vue 3?

Comment: Check this: https://therichpost.com/how-to-add-bootstrap-5-in-vue-3-application/

Comment: I've set a small boilerplate for Vue 3 with Bootstrap 5 and some other things. May will help you - https://github.com/howbizarre/starter-template_vue-3-vite-bootstrap-5-with-icons

Answer (score 271, accepted):

**Bootstrap 5 no longer needs jQuery so it's easier to use with Vue**, and no longer requires a library like bootstrap-vue.

Install bootstrap as you would any other JS module in the Vue project using npm install or by adding it to the `package.json`...

```sh
npm install --save bootstrap
npm install --save @popperjs/core
```

Next, add the Bootstrap CSS and JS components to the Vue project entrypoint (ie: `src/main.js`)...

```js
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
import "bootstrap"
```

Then, the simplest way to use Bootstrap components is via the `data-bs-` attributes. For example here's the Bootstrap Collapse component...

```html
<button 
  class="btn btn-primary" 
  data-bs-target="#collapseTarget" 
  data-bs-toggle="collapse">
  Bootstrap collapse
</button>
<div class="collapse py-2" id="collapseTarget">
  This is the toggle-able content!
</div>
```

[Demo with Navbar component](https://codeply.com/p/VyWpqRmYxB)

**Or**, you can import any Bootstrap components and "wrap" them as Vue components. For example here's the Popover component...

```js
import { Popover } from bootstrap;

const popover = Vue.component('bsPopover', {
  template: `
    <slot/>
  `,
  props: {
    content: {
      required: false,
      default: '',
    },
    title: {
      default: 'My Popover',
    },
    trigger: {
      default: 'click',
    },
    delay: {
      default: 0,
    },
    html: {
      default: false,
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    // pass bootstrap popover options from props
    var options = this.$props
    var ele = this.$slots.default[0].elm
    new Popover(ele,options)
  },
})

<bs-popover
  title="Hello Popover"
  content="This is my content for the popover!"
  trigger="hover">
    <button class="btn btn-danger">
      Hover for popover
    </button>
</bs-popover>
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/Evy1jdvloZ) |
[Read more](https://dev.to/codeply/using-bootstrap-5-with-vue-js-5fnp)

Comment: Would you please exemplify how can one use https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/select/ without manually writing all the options (they are dynamic anyway), but similar to https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-select#form-select ?

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't work if you're using TypeScript: "TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'bootstrap'"

Comment: May I ask how do you wrap bootstrap using vue-class-component in the .vue component file?

Comment: I don't suppose you have an example of this using the Vue composition API for a multi page app? I am having some issues getting the popovers to work with it

Comment: Why is import "bootstrap" required additionally to import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"?

Comment: @ShadowGames -- one is for JS and the other is for CSS

Comment: @Coreus i had the same problem, to install the TypeScript types for bootstrap fixed it for me: `npm i --save-dev @types/bootstrap` // https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/bootstrap

Answer (score 56):

Yes, you can use Bootstrap without Bootstrap-Vue.
Install these two packages with npm:

```
npm install --save @popperjs/core bootstrap@next
```

Import Bootstrap to src/main.js:

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "bootstrap";
```

Example usage for Vue Template:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button
      class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle"
      type="button"
      id="dropdownMenuButton1"
      data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
      aria-expanded="false"
    >
      Check Bootstrap
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: where is the code for vuejs?

Comment: @LaoShaw there is no extra code. Once you import the files as in this answer you'll have the CSS in all other components hosted by the root application

Comment: while bt5 does not use jquery, bt5 might still use some native js that modifies DOM directly which will not work with vue3's virtual DOM

Comment: What about adding popper.min.js? Is  this not required? The shown code above does not work for me unfortunately. The HTML is in the DOM, but the popup is not displayed when I click the button.

Comment: I get `npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for bootstrap@next.`.

Answer (score 16):

While the Bootstrap CSS can be used with ***any*** framework (React, Vue, Angular, etc), the ***Bootstrap JavaScript*** is not fully compatible with them.

Here's the official reasoning from the [Bootstrap 5 docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/javascript/#usage-with-javascript-frameworks):

> While the Bootstrap CSS can be used with any framework, the Bootstrap JavaScript is not fully compatible with JavaScript frameworks like React, Vue, and Angular which assume full knowledge of the DOM. Both Bootstrap and the framework may attempt to mutate the same DOM element, resulting in bugs like dropdowns that are stuck in the “open” position.

The docs state to use an alternative framework-specific package instead of the Bootstrap JavaScript such as **React Bootstrap**, **BootstrapVue**, and **ng-bootstrap**.

Unfortunately, BootstrapVue is only compatible with Vue2/Nuxt2 and there is no version available for Vue3/Nuxt3 yet.

Comment: https://bootstrap-vue.org/vue3

Answer (score 10):

It's easy to implement this once you understand how Bootstrap modals work. Bootstrap modals have a div element with a class of `modal fade`. When it is triggered, this element gets the `show` and `d-block` class as well. In addition, the body tag gets an additional class of `modal-open`. When the modal is closed, this process is reversed. Understanding this, we can easily implement Bootstrap 5 modals in one's code:

Import Bootstrap 5's CDN in your code. Add both the CSS and JS to your code.

Our sample Single Page Component will look like this:

```
<template>
<div>  
    <p>Test modal<a href="#" @click="modalToggle">now</a></p>
    <div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @click="modalToggle">My Modal</button>
            <div
            ref="modal"
            class="modal fade"
            :class="{ show: active, 'd-block': active }"
            tabindex="-1"
            role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
                <button
                    type="button"
                    class="close"
                    data-dismiss="modal"
                    aria-label="Close"
                    @click="modalToggle">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div v-if="active" class="modal-backdrop fade show"></div>
        </div>
</div>
</template>
```

Here we are using the basic Bootstrap 5 modal.

```
<script>
export default {
data() {
    return {
    active: false,
    }
},
methods: {
    modalToggle() {
    const body = document.querySelector("body")
    this.active = !this.active
    this.active ? body.classList.add("modal-open") : body.classList.remove("modal-open")
    },
},
}
</script>
```

Here, we have a variable `active` which is initially set false. So modal will not show up on page load. On clicking a link, we use a method to toggle this variable. This will remove the show attribute and the d-block class from our modalm and remove the `modal-open` property from the body tag.

Answer (score 3):

bootstrap 5 must have popper for run, try with this npm:

```
npm install --save bootstrap 
npm i @popperjs/core
```

Answer (score 1):

Going tag on to this answer however late it is, probably because I'll end up doing this again in a few months for another client.

I'm porting over a template from StartBootstrap into Vue, specifically the SB Admin 2 template and initially I couldn't get the navbar dropdown menu's to work. Turns out, the data attributes changed I guess between BS 4 and BS 5

Previous

```
<a
            class="nav-link collapsed"
            href="#"
            data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#collapseTwo"
            aria-expanded="true"
            aria-controls="collapseTwo"
          >
            <i class="fas fa-fw fa-cog"></i>
            <span>Components</span>
          </a>
          <div
            id="collapseTwo"
            class="collapse"
            aria-labelledby="headingTwo"
            data-parent="#accordionSidebar"
          >
            <div class="bg-white py-2 collapse-inner rounded">
              <h6 class="collapse-header">Custom Components:</h6>
              <a class="collapse-item" href="buttons.html">Buttons</a>
              <a class="collapse-item" href="cards.html">Cards</a>
            </div>
          </div>
```

You need to add `-bs` to the existing `data-` attributes as long as those attributes previously reference bootstrap functionality. Don't just go and do a Cntrl-F and Replace please.

Here is the after of the above example .

```
<a
            class="nav-link collapsed"
            href="#"
            data-bs-toggle="collapse"
            data-bs-target="#collapseTwo"
            aria-expanded="true"
            aria-controls="collapseTwo"
          >
            <i class="fas fa-fw fa-cog"></i>
            <span>Components</span>
          </a>
          <div
            id="collapseTwo"
            class="collapse"
            aria-labelledby="headingTwo"
            data-parent="#accordionSidebar"
          >
            <div class="bg-white py-2 collapse-inner rounded">
              <h6 class="collapse-header">Custom Components:</h6>
              <a class="collapse-item" href="buttons.html">Buttons</a>
              <a class="collapse-item" href="cards.html">Cards</a>
            </div>
          </div>
```

EDIT: The above assumes you've followed this answer already

https://stackoverflow.com/a/65555991/3689435

Comment: If you're using the bootstrap sass-files (see https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/customize/css-variables/)  you can get rid of "-bs" easily. So noe need to change any code. Just change die $prefix variable in SASS to "".

Answer (score 0):

please add this package :
npm install --save @popperjs/core