# How to use bootstrap in vue

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4

I am trying to use Bootstrap in my Vue project. (created with the Vue cli) 
I have installed the following things through npm.

- Bootstrap 4.6.0
- Popper.js 1.16.1
- Jquery 3.5.1

I have imported Bootsrap into my main.js

```
import 'bootstrap'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
```

The problem is that I can't use the dropdowns in Bootsrap. 
Is there anything else I should do?

Comment: If you upgrade to [tag:bootstrap-5] you won't need to use a 3rd party lib like bootstrap-vue since jquery is no longer needed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65547199/using-bootstrap-5-with-vue-3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is [bootstrap package specially for vue](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs)
you can use the following commands to install it

```
npm install bootstrap-vue
```

OR

```
yarn add bootstrap-vue
```

and then in your main.js file you can import it and use it as

```
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue';
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css';

Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
```

Comment: Can I use the basic way of just putting classes on things, or I have to use the custom tags they provide?

Comment: you need to use the custom tags that they mention in the docs and it also depends whether you use scoped/non-scoped stylings

Comment: if you found this answer useful, pls consider giving it an upvote .. thanks:)\

Comment: @HUNcut_ `Can I use the basic way of just putting classes on things`, Yes you can. You don't *have* to use the components, though I do recommend it, as it's usually less markup, and more unified. However, this is only valid for stuff that's 100% CSS based. For components that usually require Bootstrap.js like Modals, Dropdowns, Toasts, Popover/Tooltips, ect.. You will need to use their vue component counterparts.