# How to use bootstrap5 in vue3?

Tags: vuejs3, bootstrap-5

I use bootstrap 5 and vue3 . I imported both `CSS` and `JS` file in `main.js` and `CSS`file is working fine but js file is not working. The `main.js` file is below :

```
``
 import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.rtl.min.css';
 import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js';
``
```

Answer (score 0):

In `main.js`, just use below importing code:

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "bootstrap";
```

Comment: I've used it but it is not working

Comment: @imanhosseingholizadeh Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/65555991/10158551. You'd better add more info including your scenario,code,result... a reproducible demo is preferred.

Comment: I've used a slider and the slides change automatically but the arrows is not working. Means when I click on arrow to change the slides it is not working.

Comment: @imanhosseingholizadeh could not reproduce your problem when I add [carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/carousel/#with-controls) it also works.Could you also try `import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js'` or provide a reproducible demo on sandbox/codepen if necessary

Answer (score 0):

make sure to install popper js core also

```
npm i bootstrap
npm i @popperjs/core
```

Your main.js file should look something like this

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
createApp(App).use(store).use(router).mount('#app');
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js'
```