# How to you use bootstrap nav bar in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-5, popper.js

In general html, it is used well as written in docs, but it does not work properly in my vue project.Is it a problem that I didn't import popper.js? I don't think I'm exporting to html, and I'm not sure where to import it.To be precise, the normal navbar works, but the external content menu, which works on a small screen(mobile), does not work properly. help me
main.js

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './routes/index.js'

createApp(App)
//plugin
.use(router)
.mount('#app')
```

[Directory structure screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qR5s7.png)

[My WebApp screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eU6eh.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

[Bootstrap Vue](https://bootstrap-vue.org/)

OR include bootstrap CSS & JS in your `index.html'

Comment: I didn't put in the bootstrap script. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

PLease refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65547199/using-bootstrap-5-with-vue-3) It is working well for Bootstrap 5 and vue 3 for now.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34005641)