# Unable to import popper in vue project - Module not found: Error: Can't resolve @popperjs/core

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, popper.js

I'm trying to import bootstrap js files and popper in my vue 3 project. I'm getting this error, maybe I'm doing something wrong when I import the files?

```
./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@popperjs/core' in '/Users/admin/Sites/host/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js'
```

this is the code in my `main.js` file

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import './registerServiceWorker'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import 'popper.js/dist/popper.min.js'
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js'
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css'


createApp(App).use(store).use(router).mount('#app')
```

Comment: Did you run `npm i @popperjs/core` before?

Comment: I've installed it using vue cli, yes.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65547199/using-bootstrap-5-with-vue-3