# Error while using bootstrap-vue in project

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

As soon as I installed and used Bootstrap-vue in my project this error started coming and I am not able to resolve it

Details of the error

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'version') TypeError:
> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'version')
> at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/bootstrap-vue/esm/vue.js:29:58)
> at ./node_modules/bootstrap-vue/esm/vue.js (http://localhost:8080/js/chunk-vendors.js:4121:1)
> at **webpack_require** (http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:4135:33)
> at fn (http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:4368:21)
> at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/bootstrap-vue/esm/constants/events.js:66:62)
> at ./node_modules/bootstrap-vue/esm/constants/events.js (http://localhost:8080/js/chunk-vendors.js:3076:1)
> at **webpack_require** (http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:4135:33)
> at fn (http://localhost:8080/js/app.js:4368:21)
> at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/bootstrap-vue/esm/components/alert/alert.js:7:75)
> at ./node_modules/bootstrap-vue/esm/components/alert/alert.js (http://localhost:8080/js/chunk-vendors.js:788:1)

Dependencies in my project

```
"dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^3.0.0-5",
    "@popperjs/core": "2.10.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "bootstrap-vue": "2.21.2",
    "chart.js": "3.6.0",
    "core-js": "^3.31.0",
    "jkanban": "^1.3.1",
    "vue": "3.2.0",
    "vue-flatpickr-component": "9.0.5",
    "vue-router": "^4.2.2",
    "vuex": "^4.0.2"
  },
```

Comment: bootstrap-vue only supports bootstrap 4 and vue 2.  There is [initial support for Vue 3](https://bootstrap-vue.org/vue3) but specifically requires the Vue 3 migration build. 
 I suggest just removing bootstrap-vue and use bootstrap 5 by itself.  You don't need bootstrap-vue anymore.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65555991/6225326) for more details.