# Why aren't some components running in vue bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, bootstrap-vue

In vue bootstrap, b-table, b-form-input, etc. are normally compile. However, dynamic elements such as tooltip, sidebar, and carousel are not running.

This is my main.js:

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import 'bootstrap';
import BootstrapVue3 from 'bootstrap-vue-3';
import 'bootstrap-vue-3/dist/bootstrap-vue-3.css';
import VCalendar from 'v-calendar';
import 'v-calendar/style.css';
import 'bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css';
import 'jquery';
import 'popper.js';


const app = createApp(App);

app.use(BootstrapVue3);
app.use(VCalendar, {});

app.mount('#app');
```

This is my package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "myproject",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.8",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.3",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.11.3",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.23.1",
    "bootstrap-vue-3": "^0.5.1",
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "jquery": "^3.7.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "v-calendar": "^3.1.2",
    "vue": "^3.4.21",
    "vue-screen-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.13"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.16",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead",
    "not ie 11"
  ]
}
```

This is my Vue component's style:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dancing+Script:wght@400..700&family=Roboto+Condensed:ital,wght@0,100..900;1,100..900&display=swap');
@import url('bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
@import url('bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css');
@import url("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css");
```

I continued to modify the import and proceed with installation and removal about bootstrap.

Comment: There looks to be some conflicting packages here.  `bootstrap-vue-3` is, from what I can tell, a [deprecated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-vue-3) package, so I think that should be removed.  `bootstrap-vue` requires bootstrap v4, so if you want to use that specific library you need to downgrade `bootstrap`.  However, `bootstrap` v5 can be used by itself with vue 3 as explained [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65547199) meaning you could remove `bootstrap-vue` as well.

Comment: Thank you.. Solved it by deleting everything except bootstrap and creating tooltip.js separately globally. If I have one more question, I feel like vue-bootstrap is more usable than bootstrap, but if I want to use it, do I must set vue to 2 by I downgrade? 'compatConfig: { MODE: 3 }' doesn't work.